# Mock HttpClient with multiple requests

Tags: c#, httpclient, moq

I'm trying to unit test a function that makes a call to an API. I have successfully done this using a mock `HttpMessageHandler` as below which allows me to fake a response from the API:

```
private static Mock<HttpMessageHandler> GetMockHttpMessageHandler(string mockResponse)
{
    var mockMessageHandler = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>();
    mockMessageHandler.Protected()
        .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>("SendAsync", ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(), ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
        .Returns(Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage
        {
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
            Content = new StringContent(mockResponse)
        }));
    return mockMessageHandler;
}
```

So far, so good. I've been able to test half of my function, the second half makes another api call - both responses are then wrapped up into an object used by the system. The problem is, the second api needs to have a different mock response.

I thought I'd be able to change `ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>()` in the code above to `new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://LiveUrl.com/AuthenticateUserCredential")` and then have multiple `Setup/Returns` with the response changing based on the URI, but I tried it as below (with only one `Setup/Return` to test I didn't break the first half test)

```
private static Mock<HttpMessageHandler> GetMockHttpMessageHandler(string mockResponse)
{
    var mockMessageHandler = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>();
    mockMessageHandler.Protected()
        .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>("SendAsync", new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://LiveUrl.com/AuthenticateUserCredential"), ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
        .Returns(Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage
        {
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
            Content = new StringContent(mockResponse)
        }));

    return mockMessageHandler;
}
```

Now the above breaks the first api call - I get the response below:

> handler did not return a response message

Now I'm stuck - is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Answer (score 11):

Think using SetupSequence in Moq can solve this:

```
private HttpClient GetHttpClientWithHttpMessageHandlerSequenceResponseMock(List<Tuple<HttpStatusCode,HttpContent>> returns)
    {

        var handlerMock = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>(MockBehavior.Strict);
        var handlerPart = handlerMock
           .Protected()
           // Setup the PROTECTED method to mock
           .SetupSequence<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>(
              "SendAsync",
              ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(),
              ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>()
           );

        foreach (var item in returns)
        {
            handlerPart = AddReturnPart(handlerPart,item.Item1,item.Item2);
        }
        handlerMock.Verify();
        // use real http client with mocked handler here
        var httpClient = new HttpClient(handlerMock.Object)
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri("http://test.com/"),
        };
        return httpClient;
    }

    private Moq.Language.ISetupSequentialResult<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> AdddReturnPart(Moq.Language.ISetupSequentialResult<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> handlerPart,
        HttpStatusCode statusCode, HttpContent content)
    {
        return handlerPart

           // prepare the expected response of the mocked http call
           .ReturnsAsync(new HttpResponseMessage()
           {
               StatusCode = statusCode, // HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized,
               Content = content //new StringContent("[{'id':1,'value':'1'}]"),
           });
    }
```

Call the above code:

```
public void ExceuteMultipleHttpCalls()
{
            var contentSequence1 = new StringContent("{ 'id':'anId','email':'test@valid.com'}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var contentSequence2 = new StringContent("{ 'id':'anotherId','email':'anotherTest@valid.com'}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            var sequenceResponse = new List<Tuple<HttpStatusCode, HttpContent>>
            {
                new Tuple<HttpStatusCode, HttpContent>(HttpStatusCode.OK, contentSequence1),
                new Tuple<HttpStatusCode, HttpContent>(HttpStatusCode.Created, contentSequence2)
            };

            HttpClient httpClient = GetHttpClientWithHttpMessageHandlerSequenceResponseMock(sequenceResponse);
//use this httpClient to call function where this client is called multiple times.
```

}

Answer (score 1):

a function that makes a call to an API can't be unit tested, that's not a unit test, it's an integration test.
If you want to simplify your life start thinking in a functional way.

You have a function which calls an API, let's say it looks like this:

```
public string DoSomething()
{
    string myData = //here we call another API
    //here we do something with the response from the API
}
```

Now, do the API call outside of your function:

```
string myData = // api call
DoSomething(myData);

public string DoSomething(string myData)
    {
        // here we do something with myData 
        //this function no longer cares how it got the data.
    }
```

Now you can unit test your function and you can check the actual functionality and business rules without worrying about mocking anything. Everything is much simpler.

You can still test the actual API with integration tests, these would check that you get back the right HTTP codes, exceptions, the model validation is correct etc etc.

Comment: this does seem much less complex than trying to mock the httpclient responses... let me give it a try

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
    var requestUri = "http://LiveUrl.com/AuthenticateUserCredential";

    var response = Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage
    {
        StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
        Content = new StringContent(mockResponse)
    })

    mockMessageHandler
        .Protected()
        .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>("SendAsync", 
            ItExpr.Is<HttpRequestMessage>(x => x.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri.StartsWith(requestUri)),
            ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
        .ReturnsAsync(response);
```

Answer (score 1):

For those interested, the NSubstitute version of mocking multiple HTTP request would be like this:

```
    var requestUri = "http://LiveUrl.com/AuthenticateUserCredential";
    
    var response = Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage
    {
        StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
        Content = new StringContent(mockResponse)
    });
    var mockClient = Substitute.For<HttpClient>();
    
    mockClient.SendAsync(
        Arg.Is<HttpRequestMessage>(x => x.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri.StartsWith(requestUri)),
        Arg.Any<CancellationToken>())
       .Returns(response);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if previous version didn't allow for that, but if you have different HTTP calls within the same method, you can Moq each of them by specifying the HttpRequestMessage, similar to what you did. The only difference with your code is rather than initializing it as new

```
new HttpRequestMessage()
```

add it as

```
ItExpr.Is<HttpRequestMessage>(PREDICATE BY WHICH YOU WILL MATCH YOUR ROUTE)
```

for example:

```
private static Mock<HttpMessageHandler> GetMockHttpMessageHandler(string mockResponse)
{
    var mockMessageHandler = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>();
    mockMessageHandler.Protected()
        .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>(
"SendAsync", 
//BELOW IS PREDICATE
 ItExpr.Is<HttpRequestMessage>(match => 
match.Method == HttpMethod.Post && match.RequestUri == "http://LiveUrl.com/AuthenticateUserCredential"), 
//END OF PREDICATE
ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
        .Returns(Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage
        {
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
            Content = new StringContent(mockResponse)
        }));

    return mockMessageHandler;
}
```

Then you can add another setup below this one for a different URL or with a different HTTP Method

Answer (score 0):

Use [RichardSzalay.MockHttp](https://github.com/richardszalay/mockhttp) library

```
var mockHttp = new MockHttpMessageHandler();
mockHttp.When(HttpMethod.Post, url1).Respond(response1);
mockHttp.When(HttpMethod.Get, url2).Respond(response2);
var client = mockHttp.ToHttpClient(); // pass this to your SUT
```

If you have a lot of tests with HttpClient, you will eventually "reinvent" it anyway in form of helper utils